# How to exclude packages from CheckStyle analysis in a mavenized multi-module project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, checkstyle

I have a Maven project with several modules, including `org.eclipse.cdt.core`. For some reason, the customer wants to build `org.eclipse.cdt.core` as well.

I want to generate an aggregated Checkstyle report, from which some files, including all `org.eclipse.cdt.core.*` (incl. subpackages) classes are excluded.

For this purpose, I specified the `excludes` tag as

```
<excludes>**/org/eclipse/cdt/core/**/*,org.eclipse.cdt.core/src/**/*,../org.eclipse.cdt.core/src/**/*,org.eclipse.cdt.core/**/*</excludes>
```

Then I ran `mvn clean checkstyle-aggregate site`, opened the file `target/checkstyle-result.xml` and found following lines in it:

```
<file name="C:\dev\ide\org.eclipse.cdt.core\src\org\eclipse\cdt\core\AbstractExecutableExtensionBase.java">
<error line="0" severity="error" message="File does not end with a newline." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.NewlineAtEndOfFileCheck"/>
<error line="10" severity="error" message="Line is longer than 80 characters (found 81)." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.sizes.LineLengthCheck"/>
<error line="15" severity="error" message="Line is longer than 80 characters (found 83)." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.sizes.LineLengthCheck"/>
```

This means that my `<excludes>` tag doesn't work.

Then, I put the lines

```
<properties>
    <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
</properties>
```

into `pom.xml` files of all modules to be excluded from Checkstyle, but it didn't help.

How can I generate a CheckStyle report (XML or HTML), without the results for certain modules (other than taking the 180 MB large `target/checkstyle-result.xml` and removing all "wrong" file enries from there) ?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mycompany-parentproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.mycompany.parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tycho-version>0.21.0</tycho-version>
        <tycho-extras-version>0.21.0</tycho-extras-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <antrun-version>1.7</antrun-version>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Codehaus repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>${project.artifactId}-site</id>
            <url>${project.baseUri}</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- enable tycho build extension -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <format>'mycompany_'yyyyMMddHHmm</format>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>../com.mycompany.module1</module>
        <module>../com.mycompany.module2</module>
        <module>../com.mycompany.module3</module>
        <module>../org.eclipse.cdt.core</module>
    </modules>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.7</version>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <configLocation>sun-coding-standard.checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                                <excludes>**/org/eclipse/cdt/core/**/*,org.eclipse.cdt.core/src/**/*,../org.eclipse.cdt.core/src/**/*,org.eclipse.cdt.core/**/*</excludes>
                                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                            <reportSets>
                                <reportSet>
                                    <id>aggregate</id>
                                    <reports>
                                        <report>aggregate</report>
                                    </reports>
                                </reportSet>
                            </reportSets>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                            </configuration>
                            <reportSets>
                                <reportSet>
                                    <id>aggregate</id>
                                    <reports>
                                        <report>aggregate</report>
                                    </reports>
                                </reportSet>
                            </reportSets>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

**Update 1 (25.09.2014 13:03 MSK):** Tried to use suppression filters by adding

```
<configuration>
    <configLocation>sun-coding-standard.checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
</configuration>
```

with *checkstyle-suppressions.xml* being equal to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
"-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
"http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files="[\\/]org.eclipse.cdt.core[\\/]" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
    <suppress files="[\\/]org[\\/]eclipse[\\/]cdt[\\/]core[\\/]" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
    <suppress files="[\\/]org.eclipse.cdt.core[\\/]" checks="."/>
    <suppress files="[\\/]org[\\/]eclipse[\\/]cdt[\\/]core[\\/]" checks="."/>
</suppressions>
```

It didn't help.

Adding `<suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.files</suppressionsFileExpression>` to the above `<configuration>` section was of no help, either.

Answer (score 0):

This may bee a noobish question, but is there any more code in your checkstyle definition?

Usually we have something like this:

```
<fileset dir="src">
<include name="**/*.java"/>
<exclude name="com/myproject/util/*.java"/>
</fileset>
```

Where you need to say where to start scanning (source folder), what type of files to include (usually *.java) and what to exclude.
In my opinion you are trying to validate too much, and not necessary things. Checkstyle is used for validation developers code, not IDE config files.

Comment: How to name this file?